# How to refresh roles/claims of another user in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Hi we're having an issue with ASP.NET Identity.
We have an admin page that allows us to affect users to roles. (Admin etc).

The issue is when we affect a role to someone it doesn't apply for him until he logs out/logs back in.

We tried putting

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
   options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
});
```

But it causes too many issues with cookies being passed at each request etc.

Is there any way to either :

- Force logout another user
- Refresh his claims without relogging?

The only solution I have in mind atm is to use something like a list of users to be updated somewhere (redis for exemple) and check this list in a middleware and refreshSigninAsync() if the user is in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but I'd recommend you change the configuration.

I've added additional explanation on why you want to do this, in case someone wants to understand the thought process.

### The problem:

When your user signs into the app they receive a cookie, but when an account is logged out, **the user still has the valid cookie**, so they aren't really signed out.

### How to force sign-out:

Since a cookie gets re-used for as long as it's valid, you need a  way to invalidate a cookie. You invalidate a cookie through a security stamp.

Configure Identity so that it periodically re-validates the cookie. It compares the security stamp in the cookie to the database version, and, if it fails, your user needs to reauthenticate.

Add the following configuration to your services:

```cs
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions(opts => opts.ValidationInterval = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Now, you simply have to use the UserManager to find the user in the userstore, update the roles (or do whatever), then call the `UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user)` method. For example:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateRolesAsync(string userId)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    // do stuff
    await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(SomePage));
}
```

Now that causes the user to be signed out the next time the cookie is revalidated and is forced to re-authenticate.

Notes:
This is certainly **a destructive method** in terms of user experience, since any HTTP request that the user does will get terminated afterwards.
Also, it's not really an immediate sign-out, only from the perspective of the application is it immediate. The user does not know when he has been signed out, that will only be apparent when he makes an http-request.

Comment: Strangely enough I did all that. I checke the security stamp is update in the DB. I put a breakpoint in `OnValidatePrincipal` and the method gets called. But the Cookie is still not invalidated. Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: It works but it doesn't log the user out, it updates their claims and roles. I'm using dotnet 8, maybe something has changed?